# If double quotes and single quotes can be used interchangable in Javascript, why do only single quotes work in window.open()

Tags: javascript, html

I've been testing two pieces of code,

```
<a href="https://www.minds.com/scienceandtechnology" onclick="window.open('https://www.minds.com/scienceandtechnology', 'newwindow', 'width=400,height=500'); return false;">
and
<a href="https://www.minds.com/scienceandtechnology" onclick="window.open("https://www.minds.com/scienceandtechnology", "newwindow", "width=400,height=500"); return false;">
```

Both are exactly the same except for the type of quotes in windows.open(). One opens a new window, and the other opens a new tab. Why is this? I thought both quotes could be used interchangeably.

Answer (score 1):

because your `onclick="` starts a double quote....  if you make that single quote, then you can use double quote for the url

Comment: My dumb mistake. Should i delete this?

Comment: yep, you should, you'll recover your rep

Comment: héhé can't wait to see the `lick` event implemented in more browsers than it is right now

Answer (score 0):

Because your attribute value is in double quotes, and thus ends at the first double quote within it

```
<a href="https://www.minds.com/scienceandtechnology" onclick="window.open("https://www.minds.com/scienceandtechnology", "newwindow", "width=400,height=500"); return false;">
Here ---------------------------------------------------------------------^
```

You could use `'` around the attribute:

```
<a href="https://www.minds.com/scienceandtechnology" onclick='window.open("https://www.minds.com/scienceandtechnology", "newwindow", "width=400,height=500"); return false;'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first syntax right. 
1. `<a href="https://www.minds.com/scienceandtechnology" onclick="window.open('https://www.minds.com/scienceandtechnology', 'newwindow', 'width=400,height=500'); return false;">`

If we have start with double quotes then end with double quotes means syntax proper open and close by quotes.

2. `<a href="https://www.minds.com/scienceandtechnology" onclick="window.open("https://www.minds.com/scienceandtechnology", "newwindow", "width=400,height=500"); return false;">`

In this case you can start with single quote and end with single quotes.

```
<a href="https://www.minds.com/scienceandtechnology" onclick='window.open("https://www.minds.com/scienceandtechnology", "newwindow", "width=400,height=500"); return false;'>
```